# Throwing a custom NumberFormatException in Java

Tags: java, throw, numberformatexception

I am trying to throw my own NumberFormatException when convrting a String month into an Integer.  Not sure how to throw the exception.  Any help would be appreciated.  Do I need to add a try-catch before this part of the code?  I already have one in another part of my code.

```
// sets the month as a string
mm = date.substring(0, (date.indexOf("/")));
// sets the day as a string
dd = date.substring((date.indexOf("/")) + 1, (date.lastIndexOf("/")));
// sets the year as a string
yyyy= date.substring((date.lastIndexOf("/"))+1, (date.length()));
// converts the month to an integer
intmm = Integer.parseInt(mm);
/*throw new NumberFormatException("The month entered, " + mm+ is invalid.");*/
// converts the day to an integer
intdd = Integer.parseInt(dd);
/* throw new NumberFormatException("The day entered, " + dd + " is invalid.");*/
// converts the year to an integer
intyyyy = Integer.parseInt(yyyy);
/*throw new NumberFormatException("The yearentered, " + yyyy + " is invalid.");*/
```

Comment: What's happening with the code that you commented out?

Comment: @Thom I receive a unreachable statment for any code after the throw.

Comment: I took out the throw statements and added my own String to where I was catching the exception earlier in my code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

something like this:

```
try {
    intmm = Integer.parseInt(mm);
catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    throw new NumberFormatException("The month entered, " + mm+ " is invalid.");
}
```

Or, a little bit better:

```
try {
    intmm = Integer.parseInt(mm);
catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("The month entered, " + mm+ " is invalid.", nfe);
}
```

**EDIT:**  Now that you've updated your post, it seems like what you *actually* need is something like [parse(String)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29) of SimpleDateFormat

Comment: The second example is nice because it will chain together the exceptions, so you can see that the cause of the Illegal Args was the Number Format Exception.

Comment: @unbeli I took out the throw statements and added my own String to where I was catching the exception earlier in my code.
    catch (NumberFormatException NFE)
    { System.out.println(NFE.getMessage() + " has non numeric input in entry");}
Thanks for your input

Answer (score 3):

```
try {
   // converts the month to an integer
   intmm = Integer.parseInt(mm);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
  throw new NumberFormatException("The month entered, " + mm+ " is invalid.");
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right because if raised a RuntimeException ... But in this context the probability are low. However you are right.

Comment: I took out the throw statements and added my own String to where I was catching the exception earlier in my code.
    catch (NumberFormatException NFE)
    { System.out.println(NFE.getMessage() + " has non numeric input in entry");}
Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1):

Integer.parseInt() already produces NumberFormatException. In you example it seems more appropriate to throw IllegalArgumentException:

```
int minMonth = 0;
int maxMonth = 11;
try 
{
    intmm = Integer.parseInt(mm);
    if (intmm < minMonth || intmm > maxMonth) 
    {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException
      (String.format("The month '%d' is outside %d-%d range.",intmm,minMonth,maxMonth));
    }
}
catch (NumberFormatException nfe) 
{
  throw new IllegalArgumentException
  (String.format("The month '%s'is invalid.",mm) nfe);
}
```

Comment: I took out the throw statements and added my own String to where I was catching the exception earlier in my code.
    catch (NumberFormatException NFE)
    { System.out.println(NFE.getMessage() + " has non numeric input in entry");}
Thanks for your input